# spark-redis conector for scala 2.11

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, spark-redis

I'am looking for a solution where I can save my kafka streaming RDD to Redis with zscore and in Append Mode. Do we have any Connector to do this - Tried spark redis connector by RedisLabs but it is only compatible with Scala 2.10 . There is one more github by Anchormen https://github.com/Anchormen/spark-redis-connector but it is again lacking documentation and also jar is not available on maven.

```
 collection.foreachRDD(rdd =>
      {
        if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) {
        // save rdd to redis as list with zscore 
        }
      })
```

So , any suggestions please. Thanks,

Comment: spark-redis connector supports RDD for spark 2.3.x and 1.4.x See: https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis

Comment: Hi , Thanks , https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis this library solved my purpose.